# Sequence Alignment with Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am really new in algorithm programming. I know when it comes to the sequence alignment with dynamic programming, it should follow the below algorithm:

```
Alg: Compute C[i, j]: min-cost to align (the first i symbols of X) and (the j symbols of Y)(C1:cost for mismatch,C2:cost for gap alignment)
and def d[i, j] = { C1 if X[i] ≠ Y[j],0 otherwise}
Compute C[i, j]:
  case 1: align X[i] with Y[j]
    C[i, j] = C[i-1, j-1] + d[i, j]
  case 2: either X[i] or Y[j] is aligned to a gap
    C[i, j] = min{ (C[i-1, j] + C2), (C[i, j-1] + C2) }
    (C[i, j] = C[i-1, j] + C2 is case 2-1)
    (C[i, j] = C[i-1, j] + C2 is case 2-2)
Alg: C[i, 0] = iC2, ∀i
C[0, j] = jC2, ∀j
for i = 1 to m
  for j = 1 to n
    C[i, j] = min{ (case 1), (case 2-1), (case 2-2) }
return C[m, n]
```

However, for the last part:

```
for i = 1 to m
  for j = 1 to n
    C[i, j] = min{ (case 1), (case 2-1), (case 2-2) }
return C[m, n]
```

I am a little bit confused since from the previous part it just a one dimensional problem. Why should it iterate j in multiple i again and again?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the `C[i,j]` is the `memo` which stores the computed values for each combination of inputs `i` and `j`. The nested loop you've mentioned is just a walking through each cell in the 2-D matrix. The same cell is actually never calculated twice.